# e.force:navigateToURL: [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

This is a simple component, not sure what I am missing, this is exactly referred in the docs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm

**Component:**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.navigate}" value="this"/>
</aura:component>
```

**JSController:**

```
({
    navigate : function(component, event, helper) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url": 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/'
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

**Error:**

**This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:navigatetoURlcmp$controller$navigate [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:navigatetoURlcmp$controller$navigate}**

Comment: where are you viewing this component. Also where did you declared `address`

Comment: Are you previewing the component through aura:application from developer console?

Comment: I am just trying without address. It is still should take to the URL right?

Comment: did you embed this in an object page or previwing through dev console. If you are previewing through dev console force events are available only inside a LEX environment, your app is a standalone and your component will not work as expected

Comment: I am testing with standalone app. do I have add this component to LEX page and test?

Comment: @Ajay I usually don't ask people to mark answers solved but this question is kind of common situation that happens all the time when new devs start working on the platform. I had the same issue, that one little line at the bottom is such a powerful line that indicates what really is going on, so can you please mark the answer solved for the sake of this community.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you embed this in an object app builder page or previewing through dev console.

If you are previewing through dev console force events are available only inside a one.app container.

**your app is a standalone and the resulting page will be directed to lightning.force.com your force events will not work as expected.**

Preview from dev console redirect me to :

```
https://namespace-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/
```

As per [official docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm)

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in
>   Lightning Experience, Salesforce1, and Lightning communities.

Answer (score 0):

add the below dependency in the component

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToURL" type="EVENT"/>
```